# Programs close immediately when there is a specific word

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, crash

That's the problem..
And it's too strange but i'll try to explain as better as i can (i am not english)..
So.. some times ago i tried searching some words on google chrome and when loading the results page, chrome closes immediately without telling me anything.
Words like.. "hacker", "preset" and others.
The problem is not only on Google Chrome but i tried in Firefox mozilla too.
I don't know what was the problem but i didn't matter and i did my researches on my mobile phone.

Next, i was creating electronic music using FL Studio.
I have a plugin that creates synth and in it, there are some options like "load/save preset, load/save banks".
I usually load banks and i have no problems.
I tried "load preset" and FL Studio immediately closes.

It looks like my pc hates the word "preset"..

Can you tell me what's the problem?
I thought it was an antivirus (that's because i hate antiviruses).

Thanks for replies.

EDIT:
I finally found someone on internet that had the same issue searching words like "rogue", "adw", "adware".
I found that this is an adware that don't let you search these things on all browser.
So i'll try using MalwareBytes and i'll try to fix it.

Anyway thanks.

Comment: Could it be a coincidence? Have you tried to trigger the issue by using these words? or navigating to sites/windows/whatever where they may occur? Did you type this question (with the allegedly hated words) on your PC?

Comment: Sounds like a) malware, or b) parental control software [i.e. malware].

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i typed this question in my phone and if i load this page on my pc, there are no problems. But now, if i try searching the word "preset" google chrome closes/crashes.